# How to show the mounted disc title in the Unity?

Tags: unity

**Hello**.
If the system has several mounted devices - they will all be displayed on the launcher panel, but without captions (titles?). It make difficult to know which icon is responsible for a which drive. Only tip can help, but it shows a very long time.

Maybe there's a way to include displaying the disk label on launcher panel? Thanks.

*p.s. Sorry, please, for my bad English. I just learn it and accept any corrections ;)*

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about this, but it seems to me that the Unity default behavior is to display tooltips for launcher icons without a delay. It is being taken into consideration about introducing a delay for this.

Could you let us know of the ubuntu-version you are using? Perhaps the unity interface in 10.10 netbook edition used a delay.

Also update your computer (`sudo apt-get update`) as well.

As for the overlay thought, I do not think this is supported

Comment: Hello. Thank you for reply. Tips appear without delay, but if mounted devices are many and they are all connected at different times - it is not convenient to direct the cursor on each icon. It takes a long time. My version of ubuntu is 11.04